# Is there a way to automatically setup nginx and docker on a ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server

Are there any server templates or something like that? Each time I have to setup nginx and docker it's quite time comsuming.

Comment: Launch the EC2 instance from an appropriate AMI that has these things included or supply a userdata script at launch time that installs and configures whatever is needed. See [Deployment Strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/overview-deployment-options/deployment-strategies.html).